# What is the word that fits into these sentence?

Tags: meaning

I'm calling to remind you of your o**r ** * bill. The payment date was last Monday and we haven't received anything from you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a puzzle question, and is not about learning English.

Comment: Puzzles are a good way to test one's English skills.

Answer (score 5):

Presumably the missing word is "overdue".